# How to send email with contact form on Wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get a simple contact form to work with my wordpress site but cannot get it to work. I dont want to use any plugin, I just want to do it using PHP. So I put this file in root dir of my wordpress installation on my hostgator hosted site

www.example.com/sendmail.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$to = "myemail@yahoo.com";
$from= $_POST['email'];
$fname= $_POST['fname'];
$lname= $_POST['lname'];
$message= $_POST['message'];
$subject = "Request email";
$headers = "From:" .$from;

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}
?>
```

This is the contact-us form on www.example.com/contact-us

```
    <form action="http://www.example.com/sendmail.php" method="post">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <input id="fname" name="name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <input id="lname" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Enter your massage for us here. We will get back to you within 2 business days." rows="7"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
<!--                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>-->
                                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"  value="Submit">
 </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
```

If i try to visit this page www.example.com/sendmail.php, it gives 200 success ok message. However if I try to fill the form and then it sends the email, i am not able to recieve it.

Is there anything I am missing or I need to check ?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting these variables `$fname= $_POST['fname']; $lname= $_POST['lname'];` on `sendmail.php`

But your html form input fields does not have name for `fname` and `lname` .

So use the below one :

```
 <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <input id="fname" name="fname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <input id="lname" name="lname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Instead of :

```
 <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <input id="fname" name="name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <input id="lname" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Hope it helps you.